# How to write the merge function for Collectors.toMap()

Tags: java, collections, java-stream

Here `UserMst` is the object and `users` is the List from which I get LoginId && TenantId.

````
LinkedHashMap<String, String> Tmap = users.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(
                    UserMst::getLoginId, UserMst::getTenantId,
                        (x, y)-> ((x=="1") ? "Rocks" : (x=="2")
                                           ? "Mocks" : (x=="3")
                                           ? "Docs"  : (x=="4")
                                           ? "Pocks" : "")
                                   + " ,  " + ( (y=="1") ? "Rocks": (y=="2")
                                                         ? "Mocks": (y=="3")
                                                         ? "Docs" : (y=="4")
                                                         ? "Pocks": ""),
                        LinkedHashMap::new));


///////////////////

LinkedHashMap<String, String> Tmap =
    users.stream().collect(
        Collectors.toMap( UserMst::getLoginId, UserMst::getTenantId,
        (x, y)-> x + ", " + y, LinkedHashMap::new)); 

```

It gives output as answer:: rajat=1,2,3 dave=1,2 milind=2,3
I just need these 1,2,3,4 replaced with strings
````

Comment: Did you know that you can use blocks in lambdas? No need to put everything in a single statement like this super complex ternary thingy. Like `(x,y) -> {...some normal code here ...}`

Comment: Your merge function doesn't make much sense. Can you show sample input and output?

Comment: Besides, you are comparing Strings with ==, which is wrong.

Comment: How to add conditions for key value mappers of Collection.map

Comment: Put the details directly in the question and not in the comments, they are unreadable in here.

Comment: is it clear Now!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The 3rd argument to `Collectors.toMap()` is the merge function, which is a function that gets two values of the `Map`, and returns a "merged" value. This is used to merge multiple values that correspond with the same key.

It is not suitable to transform the values of your map from "1","2","3",... to other `String`s.

To replace the numeric values with `String`s, you can perform the transformation in the value mapper:

```
LinkedHashMap<String, String> Tmap = 
    users.stream()
         .collect(Collectors.toMap(UserMst::getLoginId,
                                   u -> convert(u.getTenantId()),
                                   (x, y)-> x + ", " + y,
                                   LinkedHashMap::new));
```

where `convert` is a method that accepts a `String` such as "1" and returns the corresponding `String`.

For example:

```
public static convert (String x)
{
    return x.equals("1")?"Rocks":x.equals("2")?"Mocks":x.equals("3")?"Docs":x.equals("4")?"Pocks":"";
}
```

Or you can add to `UserMst` class a method that returns the `String` corresponding with the `getTenantID()` of that instance, and then simply write:

```
LinkedHashMap<String, String> Tmap = 
    users.stream()
         .collect(Collectors.toMap(UserMst::getLoginId,
                                   UserMst::getTenantString,
                                   (x, y)-> x + ", " + y,
                                   LinkedHashMap::new));
```

Comment: I'd just add to the answer what `mergeFunction` paramether in `toMap()` method does - just to explain why OPs code doesn't work.

Comment: @Eran Please ready whole question again!!!   i am getting it as an output i need to manupulate it before storing it to  map How an i do it?????????????

Comment: @RajatDiwate I understand you want rajat=Rocks,Mocks,Docs instead of rajat=1,2,3. That's what my answer will produce.

Comment: You know, you can use `switch` over `String` (though, the upcoming `switch` expressions would make it even better). It’s worth mentioning the alternative, `groupingBy(UserMst::getLoginId, LinkedHashMap::new, mapping(UserMst::getTenantString, joining(", ")))`